# Watson Assistant response with lag

Tags: node.js, watson-assistant

I built a conversational IVR with Watson Assistant. Everything works fine but the response from the assistant is kind of slow. When a caller calls in, the assistant will ask a name, which is pretty quick. But after the caller says a name, the assistant takes a time a little bit long than normal. Could anyone can help me out with this. The whole conversation is pretty short: caller says a name, then the IVR finds the name as entity and reply.

Comment: Welcome to SOF. Can you add some code as to what IVR is doing when the name is called. Did you debug as to what happens when it receives the name

Comment: Sarmahdi, thanks for your help. I am using Node-Red and built a SOE frame by Watson Voice gate. It is very simple. I set person-name entities in a Watson Assistant skill. When a call is in, the assistant greeting with "Thanks for calling. Please name a person you would like to speak to.". Then the caller response with a name, for example Carson. The assistant will check a list which has 25 items and see if the name is in the list. if in the list, it will transfer the call to a number set by the name. It is pretty simple and the logic is clear as a mud. It works fine except the response lag.

Comment: Are you connecting to some backend API after initial conversation? like passing the name or context?

Comment: Quantum, Yes. I do.